# getline () return invalid arguments when it should be working

Tags: c

I tried to use getline but i get invalid argument error. How to fix the code below?

EDIT: as Jonathan Leffler and kaylum pointed out, the errno seem to be set by another function, not by getline().

```
        FILE *in = fopen ("input.txt", "rb");
        if (in == NULL)
                exit (-1);

        char *buf = NULL;
        size_t n = 0;

        getline (&buf, &n, in);

        printf ("error: %s\n", strerror (errno));
```

Comment: When asking about an error show the exact error. In this case it looks like you are incorrectly flagging an error without checking whether `getline` actually succeeded or not. There is no guarantee that `errno` is set unless the call fails. Check the `getline` return value before calling `strerror`.

Comment: No library routine in standard C or POSIX sets `errno` to zero.  You should assume that functions are permitted to modify `errno` even if they don't report an error — so it is only valid to check `errno` after a routine has reported an error.

Comment: It works for me. https://onlinegdb.com/SydJuZAzu